# How to configure IIS to host multiple websites?

Tags: windows, iis, configuration

Suppose there are a.com,b.com,how to host them both with the same IIS?

**EDIT**

It's not hello.domain.com and goodbye.domain.com,but two totally different domain names

Comment: This is probably more appropriate to http://serverfault.com than to here...

Answer (score 1):

You should look at creating multiple websites and using different host headers. Note if you are developing on Windows XP then you can only host 1 website (without using a tool downloaded from the internet).

Refer to these articles:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190008
http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/

Note: This question is better asked at ServerFault.com :)

Comment: Yep it will still apply. Remember that a domain name is translated into an IP address. Using Host Headers is how you can host multiple web sites from the same IP address and different domain names. Hopefully this will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Define multiple "Web sites" (as much as desired amount of virtual hosts), then for each web site, right click > properties > "web site" tab > "Advanced" button on "IP adress" row and there define your virtual hosts in "Host header value" field

Comment: How to define "web sites"?Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

i'm going completely off of memory.  but what Oliver means (i believe).  is in IIS.  you click to create new website.  name it whatever you want.  in the properties section you will want to click on the tab that will show host names.  Probably will also show text for multiple identies.  leave IP address as all unassigned.  and put in the domain name you want to answer.  this can be my.domain.com or just domain.com or domain.local or whatever.

Do that for each website.  Also in the properties you will need to select the domain's source files (which point to directories on the server's harddrives).

[example for older iss 4 and 5](http://www.iisanswers.com/Top10FAQ/t10-hostheaders.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. I solved issue. I just updated my server IP in Domain Name registered site (it will take some time for reflecting depend on your operator).
2. In IIS expand top menu then in site go to default site

   - right click on default site go to edit Binding then edit port.
   - Add any other port than default (8080) save
3. In IIS expand top menu then right click on site then click on add website.
4. Give name to website select default app pool  pass physical path of application then below in binding select HTTP protocol in IP field set default All Unassigned in port add default port (must be 80) in host name add host name.
5. restart website and browse